# Run Symfony app by calling index.php from command line (cli)

Tags: php, symfony

I am beginning to use Symfony (I'm coming from Codeigniter) and I'm trying to figure out how I can call an existing web app using the command line.

In Codeigniter, you could execute the main entry script using the cli (an index.php) and pass the route (the url path) as a parameter. The Route module would then call the appropriate controller, and the the same output that would have been written to a the browser is actually printed into the cli.

In Symfony this does not seem to be the case. I can call the public/index.php script, and the home page is printed into the cli. But then I try to pass the route (the url path) as parameter and it always prints the home page.

Is there a way to run an entire app by calling the public/index.php from the cli, passing the route as parameter?

I have seen that there's a power Console component in Symfony, but it looks like I'd need to write extra code to use the functionality already written for web requests.

Any ideas?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: What's stopping you from running `curl https://myapp.local/myroute` on your app and get the output?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use The Console Component, this is very simple. Or create the custom controller with a route and get/pass data via curl (API).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But if I need to use the Console component, I have to write new code for each route, effectively duplicating the same functionality of the web controllers. Is this correct? Doesn't seem ideal to me...

Would there be a way to share the code of the web controllers and the console component, to avoid duplication?

Comment: It doesn't correct. You do not need the duplicate. You can create service container with your own logic. As an example - each functionality can be some service, and you can get access from controller or console command or where you want to this service. Look this example for Symfony 3 https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/239/how-to-create-and-execute-a-custom-console-command-in-symfony-3

Comment: Thanks. So I guess I could register the controller as a service, and then call the controller from the console command? This way I can write the business logic only once (in the controller)

Comment: Well, I'm trying to call a Controller's method from a Command, and I'm getting the error "Call to a member function has() on null" in ControllerTrait.php (line 222). The Controller is loaded as a Service.

Comment: Did you include the ContainerAwareCommand class into your command instead of extending the Command class? Or can you show the code?